# Publishing WebJob to Azure overrwrites website NLog.config

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, nlog, azure-webjobs

I use VS2017 to publish my .NET web application to Azure App Service, and a .NET console application to Azure WebJobs.

When I publish the console application, the **NLog.config** file in my web application root gets overwritten by the console application's NLog.config.  These NLog.config files are not identical, and therefore it breaks the logging of my web app.

I have discovered that WebJobs are published to the App_Data folder of the web application, so each has it's own NLog.config:

```
Web Application: wwwroot\NLog.config
WebJob:          wwwroot\app_data\jobs\triggered\MyWebJob\NLog.config
```

If I publish the WebJob first, then the web application, all is good.  However that means each time I change & publish the WebJob, I have to re-deploy my web app.

Any suggestions how to resolve this?  Or even some path to better diagnosing the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that when you publish the WebJob, it writes **both** `wwwroot\NLog.config` and `wwwroot\app_data\jobs\triggered\MyWebJob\NLog.config`? Also, note that you can publish a Web App and WebJobs in a single gesture if you associate them in VS.

Comment: Yes, exactly - the WebJob's NLog.config is written to both locations.   Good idea about associating them in VS, I'll look into it.

Comment: Is this nlog.config just a regular file that is marked as Copy Always in your project? Do you see the same behavior if you add a dummy file next to it with the same Copy setting? I doubt the publishing logic has any special handling for this file.

Comment: Yes, it is Copy Always.  I added a dummy.txt with Copy Always to the WebJob, and it too was published to the web application root, AND the WebJob directory.   Odd.

Comment: Must be a publishing bug somewhere. Is the WebJob using .NET Core or regular full framework? Also, can you check if there are any NuGet updates available for some package related to WebJobs publishing?

Comment: It uses package Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish, which is current (v2.0.0 released 5/8/18).    WebJob is using full .NET Framework.   I agree this must be a publishing bug.   I appreciate your help.

Comment: Interestingly, I can't repro. I created brand new Console App, added a 'Copy Always' json file, and chose Publish As Azure WebJob. No repro. Then I upgraded the publish package from 1.1 to 2.0 and published again. Still no json in wwwroot, only in the right place. Can you try the same to see if it repros for you in such minimal scenario?

Comment: Yes, I will definitely give that a try.    I also updated the VSIX extension "Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools", but still no success.   I noticed the output from publishing shows the NLog issue:     
`Updating file (myapp-test\app_data\jobs\triggered\MyApp-WebJob\Mailer.dll).
Updating file (myapp-test\app_data\jobs\triggered\MyApp-WebJob\MyWebJob.exe).
Updating file (myapp-test\app_data\jobs\triggered\MyApp-WebJob\MyWebJob.exe.config).
Updating file (myapp-test\NLog.config).
Publish Succeeded.`

Comment: I was able to reproduce this from a clean solution, without NLog.  I added "TextFile1.txt" to the console app, and it's copied to both the WebJob and Web App.   Output from build/publish:  `Updating (WebApplicationWebJobNlogIssue\app_data\jobs\triggered\ConsoleApp1\TextFile1.txt).
Updating file (WebApplicationWebJobNlogIssue\TextFile1.txt).`

Comment: I will ask the VS publishing expert to take a look.

Comment: Great, I appreciate that.  I will continue to look at this as well.   I'm happy to send my repro project if it helps.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue. Looks like a bug in the WebJobs target. We will get it fixed. As a work-around, can you try adding the following line in the csproj.

Right below the line that has the webjobs.targets import, please add this empty target and that should fix the issue temporarily.
  `<Import Project="..\webjobs.targets"  />
  <Target Name="CollectFilesFromContent" />`

Comment: Please apply the above work-around only to the WebJob project. Don't add this work-around to the Web App. Adding this to the Web App will prevent any content files from getting published.

Comment: I added this workaround but now I cannot load the project.   `<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.1.0\tools\webjobs.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.1.0\tools\webjobs.targets')" />
  <Import Project="..\webjobs.targets" />
  <Target Name="CollectFilesFromContent" />
</Project>`    I get an error that the webjobs.targets cannot be found.   Do I need to add an empty webjobs.targets file?

Comment: Okay, got this workaround working.  I re-read your instructions and realized I was not supposed to include the `<Import..>` line, just the `<Target...>` line.   This workaround resolves the issue -- file from the web job is not writting to the web app folder.   I appreciate the help!